# Python best way to assume a value from dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary

I am reading a dictionary from external source, let's say

```
data = {'name': 'James', 'gender': 'male'}
```

And sometimes

```
data = {'name': 'James', 'gender': 'male', 'article': {'title':'abc'}}
```

And sometimes

```
data = {'name': 'James', 'gender': 'male', 'article': None}
```

I know that I can use `.get(key, default)` when I am not sure if `articles` exists in data:

```
articles = data.get('article', {}).get('title')
```

But sometimes, they provide the element with `None` value, so the above doesn't work and cause error, and need to become:

```
articles = data.get('article') or {}
```

But this requires me to break it into 2 statements instead of chaining up to get values from article as mentioned earlier.

Is there a more elegant way to do that, something like:

```
data.get('article', {}, ignore=[None])
```

or

```
data.get_ignore_none('article', {})
```

Comment: you may want to show the way `data` would look when it **does** have `articles` and say that it might not exist instead of the other way around.  As written your example `data` and what you are trying to do with it seem completely unrelated.

Comment: So, ultimately, you want `data["article"]["title"]` as the string value, or None, without errors?

Comment: Which Python version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off you seem to think that using an [`or`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#boolean-operations-and-or-not) expression to discard [false-y results](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing) from `data.get('article')` can only be done in two statements like the following:

```
temp = data.get('article') or {}
articles = temp.get("title")
```

However you can just put brackets around the first expression and call `.get("title")` on it's return value directly:

```
articles = (data.get('article') or {}).get("title")
```

But I feel this is not particularly readable or efficient, when `'article'` missing or `None` then you are creating a new mapping and checking it for `"title"` unnecessarily.

One possible solution is to use a function like the following:

```
def nested_get(mapping, *keys):
    """gets a value from a nested dictionary,
if any key along the way is missing or None then None is returned
will raise an AttributeError if a value in the chain is not a dictionary (support the .get method)"""
    current = mapping
    for item in keys:
        current = current.get(item)
        if current is None:
            return None
    return current
```

Then you would do `nested_get(data, "article", "title")` to try to get `data["article"]["title"]` without throwing errors if `data["article"]` is None or missing.

I tested this with the following code:

```
test_cases = [{'name': 'James', 'gender': 'male'},
              {'name': 'James', 'gender': 'male', 'article': {'title':'abc'}},
              {'name': 'James', 'gender': 'male', 'article': None}]

for case in test_cases:
    print(case)
    print(nested_get(case,"article","title"))
    print()

#the follwing will raise an error since mapping["a"] would need to be a dict
nested_get({"a":5}, "a","b")
```

Comment: I think `articles = (data.get('article') or {}).get("title")` is the best option so far, but it is not obvious enough for the next guy to understand without actually placing a comment of purpose.

Comment: @JamesLin is the edit sufficient? I'm not a huge fan of compound expressions like that since it is not immediately obvious what it is suppose to accomplish.

Comment: I think the function approach will work, I would change it to `nested_get(obj, (('article', {}), ('authors', [])))` to allow specifying default variables.

Comment: I don't think that would work, you could specify the default if it was not found but every default before that would have to be `{}` or using `.get` would fail. I was considering changing it to do `try:current = current[item] ; except (IndexError, KeyError): return None` so that it was compatible with lists too.

Answer (score 2):

By default `.get()` will return `None` if the key doesn't exist. In your case you are returning an empty dictionary.

Now, I don't know what error is being raised, but I am sure its from `get_stuff(article)` rather than your list comprehension.

You have a few ways to solve this:

1. Modify `get_stuff` so that it takes the value directly, rather than each element. This way, you are just passing it `[get_stuff(value) for value in data.get('articles')]`. Now, in `get_stuff`, you simply do this:

   ```
   def get_stuff(foo):
     if not foo:
       return None
     for item in foo:
       do stuff
     return normal_results
   ```
2. Add a filter in your list comprehension:

   ```
   [get_stuff(foo) for foo in data.get('articles') if data.get('articles')]
   ```

Comment: the error he get is probably `TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable` when that key is in the dict and have a value of None

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to accomplish with adding a conditional in the comprehension, it would be checked for each iteration in the loop so either it does an unnecessary check if `articles` is present and a sequence, or it still raises the TypeError if `articles` is missing.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid I have updated my question, so your answer may seem a bit outdated, sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing wrong with using exceptions to break out early in this case. I'm assuming you want the title value, or None, no matter what the data is. The following function will work (for Python 3).

```
def get_title(d):
    try:
        return data.get("article").get("title")
    except AttributeError:
        return None
```

If the outer dictionary gets a None as value or by default it will raise the AttributeError on the None object which you just catch.

Comment: Yes using exception is fine, but imagine when you deal with fields like `article` then you will have a lot of try catch blocks, seems a bit verbose.

Comment: It's 4 lines. Don't get paralyzed by verbosity.  This already deals with `article`.

Comment: 4 lines is fine, but like I mentioned earlier, if I am dealing with 10s of elements like 'article' it will get verbose.

Comment: You can just make the `"article"` string a variable that you pass in. It will be the same. You don't need any more try blocks.

Comment: But doing it in a function prevents me to perform arbitrary chaining.

Comment: I like Tadhg's function approach, and yes I know it's similar to yours, so I am going to give you an upvote.

Comment: @JamesLin my approach is identical to this, I just take the elements to retrieve as arguments! (or are you referring to the first suggestion which I personally don't actually like)

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen yes I know both are the same in the core logic, hence I gave his answer an upvote, but accepted yours because it has the second parameter to allow more flexibility.

Answer (score 0):

how about this

```
>>> data = {1:(42,23)}
>>> [x for x in data.get(1) or []]
[42, 23]
>>> [x for x in data.get(32) or []]
[]
```

use `or` to change to your default value in case you get `None` or something that eval to false

**Edit**:

In the same way you can `or` and brackets to get desired output in one line

```
articles = (data.get('article') or {}).get('title')
```

and with just that you handle all 3 cases.

you can also define `get_ignore_none` like for example

```
def get_ignore_none(data_dict, key, default=None):
    if key in data_dict:
        value = data_dict[key]
        return value if value is not None else default
    return default
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're loading this data from an external source, one option is a preprocessing step *as soon as* you load it:

```
from collections import Mapping

def remove_none(d):
    for k, v in d.items():
        if v is None:
            del d[k]
        if isinstance(v, Mapping):
            remove_none(v)

data = load_data_from_somewhere()
remove_none(data)
```

Now you can just use `get` everywhere you need to:

```
articles = data.get('article', {}).get('title')
```

Comment: I think that's close to what I wanted to do, my example is a bit trivial, sometimes the problem buries deep inside levels of dictionary... yes you can traverse the dictionary but I think it's not explicit enough.